# bash glob wildcard * with natural sort order

Tags: bash, glob, natural-sort

I am aware that in bash you can naturallly sort a `ls` command with the flag `-1v` . However I am using a program that expands the wildcard `*` in paths like:

`./mybin /path/to/directory_*/shard-*` and once this expansion occurs the order is the typical alphabetical order we see in bash.

Is there a way to set beforehand the shell to expand `*` in a naturally sorted way ?

It seems like `zsh` can do that: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers

Comment: Globs use `LC_COLLATE` to determine sort order.

Comment: Best practice is, and has pretty much always been, to pad your numbers so that natural sort and ASCII sort are identical.